# Linked list program crashes

Tags: c, linked-list

I was implementing a linked list with 3 elements using structs. It was working fine before I introduced the function to calculate the number of elements in the linked list `Linked_list`. Following is the code for the program in C.

**C**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* Linked_list();

int Length();

int main()
{
    int length;
    Linked_list();
    length = Length();
    printf("%d", length);
}

struct node* Linked_list() {
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* second = NULL;
    struct node* third = NULL;

    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    third->next = NULL;

    printf("%d %d", head->data, second->data);
}

int Length(struct node* head){
    struct node* current = head;
    int count = 0;

    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Run in debugger, what's your error, whathaveyoutried.com, etc.

Comment: length = Length();  no arguments?

Comment: it doesn't shows me an error, but it crashes after outputting the first and second data elements of the linked list. That is it executes the first function properly.

Comment: @djechlin it doesn't show me any error.

Comment: @SumitGera - What are you using to build/run this? It compiles and runs for me giving an out put of `1 2` for the data elements and `0` for length (expected since you didn't pass in a `head`)

Comment: I am using codeblocks with mingw gcc-4.3.2 compiler. yeah it misses the return statement in the main and input argument to the function `Length();`.

Comment: I wouldn't use any compiler that doesn't give you an error and a few warnings when it sees that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring and calling `Length()` as it had no parameters `length = Length();`

But when you define it it does have one parameter:

```
int Length(struct node* head)
```

This is legal, but what happens is that the actual function doesn't get a `head` parameter to work with and that is why it crashes.

You should return `head` from `Linked_list()` (which is not currently returning anything) and feed that to `Length()`.

```
struct node* Linked_list() {
    ....

    printf("%d %d", head->data, second->data);
    return  head;
}
```

And then on main:

```
struct node* head = Linked_list();
length = Length(head);
```

There might be other problems though.

Comment: Thank you. But Isn't it necessary to include the input argument type in the function `int Length()`?

Comment: It is good practice and you should do so, but for compatibility with older `C` versions, the compiler allows you not to.

Comment: program runs fine now. thanks.